# How do I get events Presented And Dismissed from SideMenu

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented SideMenu framework from  https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu.

I want to implement method from SideMenu class in my own class so that I can change my UIImage when side menu is Presented or Dismissed.

This is the method from Side Menu class

```
// MARK: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate protocol methods

// return the animator when presenting a viewcontroller
// rememeber that an animator (or animation controller) is any object that aheres to the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol
open func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    self.presenting = true
    SideMenuTransition.presentDirection = presented == SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController ? .left : .right
    return self
}

// return the animator used when dismissing from a viewcontroller
open func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    presenting = false
    return self
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to subclass UISideMenuNavigationController to get ViewDidAppear and ViewDidDisappear. Check this answer [How do I insert code in ViewDidAppear and ViewDidDisappear From other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878935/how-do-i-insert-code-in-viewdidappear-and-viewdiddisappear-from-other-class)