# How do I insert code in ViewDidAppear and ViewDidDisappear From other class

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change button image whenever UISideMenuNavigationController Appear Or Disappear.

This is the class that has a button.

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var btnMenu: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

This is the other class that i want to insert code.

```
open class UISideMenuNavigationController: UINavigationController {

      override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewDidAppear(animated)

         // insert some code here but from MenuViewController class
      }

      override open func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        // insert some code here but from MenuViewController class
      }
}
```

I don't want to change UISideMenuNavigationController class because it is framework from pods.

I'm using framework side menu from https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

I need to change button image whenever Side Menu Appear Or Disappear. I can't find the way from ReadMe Side Menu. That's why I think need to insert the code in ViewDidAppear and ViewDidDisappear Method from Side Menu Class but don't want to break the class.

Comment: How are you going to insert code into it without changing it?  You might need to explain what this means.

Comment: I have updated the answer @SonofaBeach

Comment: Again... how are you going to "insert code" without "breaking" the class.  What does this even mean?  As suggested by both answers below, you can subclass it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to subclass `UISideMenuNavigationController` and override the `viewDidAppear` & `viewDidDisappear` methods to invoke a delegate.

```
protocol MyUISideMenuDelegate {
    func menuDidAppear(_ menu:MyUISideMenuNavigationController) -> Void
    func menuDidDisappear(_ menu:MyUISideMenuNavigationController) -> Void
}

open class MyUISideMenuNavigationController: UISideMenuNavigationController {

    var menuDelegate: MyUISideMenuDelegate? 

    override open func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewDidAppear(animated)
         self.menuDelegate?.menuDidAppear(self)
    }

    override open func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        self.menuDelegate?.menuDidDisappear(self)
    }
}
```

Then have you view controller with the button implement the protocol and set itself as the delegate.

You could also have your menu subclass send `NSNotification` and have any other objects that are interested subscribe to those.  This way you completely decouple the menu and the other classes.

Comment: No error for the code but I got error when I was trying to swipe the menu. this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key leftSide.

Comment: That means that the storyboard scene refers to an outlet `leftSide` but the class for that scene doesn't have an `@IBOutlet` `leftSide`.  Check you have set the custom class correctly and created the outlet if required

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `MenuViewController` class could have a function that changes the image on the button.  Eg, `func changeButtonMenuImage()`.
2. Your 'UISideMenuNavigationController' (**or a subclass of it**) could have some sort of connection to the MenuViewController either as a property, instance variable or an IBOutlet.  Eg, `@IBOutlet var menuController: MenuViewController`
3. Then your `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` can call it's function.  Eg, `menuController.changeButtonMenuImage()`

Comment: I don't want to change UISideMenuNavigationController class because it is framework. Thanks

Comment: You could subclass it, and then make these same changes to the subclass.  Answer updated to include this.